# How to prove that a set R\Z is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

So I've been trying to prove that a set $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z}$ is an open set but I don't quite know where to start since the relative complement is still infinite.
So theoretically in $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z}$ one could pick a real number as close to an integer as needed but you could of course never pick the integer itself. So my idea was that $a-\epsilon<a$ for any $\epsilon>0$ with $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ but I have a feeling I'm doing it wrong.
Any ideas or hints on how to solve this properly?

Comment: What can you say about $\mathbb{Z}$ when you consider it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $\mathbb{Z}$ closed or open?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint! So since $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ the relative complement which is $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z}$ has got to be open, right?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each real number $r$, you can find an integer $n$ such that $n\le r<n+1$. Especially if $r$ is not an integer then $n<r<n+1$. Take $\varepsilon=\min\{n+1-r,r-n\}/2$.

---

There is a more simple proof (if you know about some basic topology.) For each integer $n$, open interval $(n,n+1)$ is open and
$$\Bbb{R-Z}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} (n,n+1).$$
That is, $\Bbb{R-Z}$ is a union of countable many open sets so $\Bbb{R-Z}$ is open.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I somehow didn't consider using a union of open intervals to prove a set open but it makes sense and is short, thanks again!